# RStudio: I cannot knit to PDF, Error: could not find function "head" Execution halted

Tags: r, pdf, rstudio, head

When i try to knit a .Rmd file to PDF (or html or word) in RStudio i get the following error: could not find function "head"
Execution halted
What do i do?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. `head` is a base R function so it should be available. Perhaps you have some code in the wrong place somewhere? Can you show us a minimal document that recreates the error for you?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure you are loading the utils package in a code chunk?

````
```{r load-packages, include=FALSE}
library(utils)```
````

Comment: Since utils is a base package I have not encountered this problem before, but without any sample code I would suggest ensuring that the rmd is loading in the utils package which contains the 'head' function.